# Partially controlling LDAP BindDN parameter

Tags: ldap, ldap-injection

In an application I was assessing, I found an interesting piece of code that took my attacker-supplied input and put it into the bindDN while preparing to connect to an LDAP server.

```
[USERNAME]@domain.com
```

Specifically, I can inject whatever I want into the [USERNAME] in the above sample bindDN, including something like `testusername@anotherdomain.com@domain.com`. I do not control the LDAP URL though. Is there anything risky security-wise with this small bug?

Comment: Have you read https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_LDAP_Injection_(OTG-INPVAL-006)? Without knowing what the LDAP is used for, there could also be flaws in the business logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following points are worth considering in any attempt to leverage this, though I don't believe anything except attempts at denial of service would work.

Where [LDAP URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4516) are used, these *do not* support in-band credentials in the URL, as the (now deprecated) method that HTTP URLs used "`http://user:password@host/`". There should be no way to inject a malformed bind username into such URLs (typically used for [search queries](https://ldap.com/ldap-urls/)) to alter their effect. However, some directory implementations support non-DN usernames in a bind operation — specifically Active Directory (userPrincipalName); or OpenLDAP with SASL and/or `olcAuthIdRewrite`/ `olcAuthzRegexp`. *If* OpenLDAP is configured to take a non-DN bind username (in the form of an email address or uid @realm), or otherwise uses the [*rwm* overlay](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-rwm) to rewrite in bindDN context, *and* formulates an LDAP search URL to determine the real user DN, this will only be as robust as the administrator's rewrite instructions, and *could* be subject to injection of malformed usernames. This is fairly unlikely, and probably very difficult to do blind (without being able to inspect the rules). I suspect it's simply an AD backend here though.

On the wire, [the bind request](https://ldap.com/ldapv3-wire-protocol-reference-bind/) will be a DER encoded structure of the form

```
 0   53: SEQUENCE {
 2    1: . INTEGER 1
 5   48: . [APPLICATION 0] {
 7    1: . . INTEGER 3
10   33: . . OCTET STRING    
       : . . . 63 6E 3D .. ..            cn=user,ou=... 
45    8: . . [0] 'password'
       : . . }
       : . }
```

An anonymous bind will already have been created, establishing the connection. Unless there is some horrible bug in the underlying ASN.1/LDAP library (e.g. to let you formulate a username with a DER parseable trailing password of your choosing, for brute force) then the best you can probably do is exercise the [parsing, escaping, or UTF-8 encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514) layers, or determine the maximum size of a DN (not defined by LDAP schema).

The best you might be able to achieve is:

- denial of service, possibly through the use of very long or dubiously escaped/quoted usernames
- lockout of an arbitrary user - assuming the directory implements this, e.g. AD policies, and the directory service is not otherwise accessible (in which case it's probably trivial to achieve in other ways)
- attempt to enumerate other users in the same domain/directory, how practical  this will be depends on feedback during the authentication attempts (see [this for LDAP error codes](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch12/))
- attempt to find another user with the same password as this user (though how that might be useful, I don't know)